# Same CSS, Same Page, Different Rendering

Tags: css, rendering

Can anyone explain the cause of this difference shown below?

in the bottom panel, the colored bars render thicker than the top panel.

[image]

The CSS is the same for both;

```
.colored-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
}
```

Browser: Chrome 84

Please see live repro here: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tobystfd/pen/BaKJqGd)

What i see in CodePen;

[image]

Comment: They indeed are same.

Comment: Your codepen shows no difference

Comment: They seem to be the same in your codepen indeed.

Comment: thanks for unanimous feedback, possibly my screen then?

Comment: have added what i see in codepen example - please confirm this is not what you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have turned on magnification in the browser. Disable it and everything should be correct.

125% magnification show exactly the same problem as on your screenshot.

#### Update 1:

Also if I set scaling directly in the Windows screen settings to 125% the problem shows up.

#### Update 2:

I may found a possible solution. Just use pseudoelements instead of normal ones and everything seems to be working perfectly, but I didn't do an extensive testing.

```css
.kpi {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 56px;
  width: 175px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  width: 45px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex space-between">
  <div class="col d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
     <div class="row kpi mb10 d-flex justify-content-between">
       <div class="box">
         Test
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         Test
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         Test
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row kpi mb10 d-flex justify-content-between">
       <div class="box">
         Test
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         Test
       </div>
       <div class="box">
         Test
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my browser zoom is set to 100% though. so don't think it is this. I have previously noticed, as you have, that the issue is effected by zoom though.

Comment: @tubbsy it happens also with system wide scaling, so maybe that is your issue

Comment: yes! this is it! can't thank you enough @Magiczne !

Comment: extra points if anyone knows if there is a way to guard against this happening for users who have 125% windows settings?

Comment: @tubbsy it's rather not a solution but a hack, to make height of the element smaller by a fraction of a pixel. For example `1.75px`. But there is no any guarantee that it will work everywhere and every time.

Comment: @tubbsy added possible solution

Comment: I have also found that as long as the browser zoom matches the windows zoom setting - all pixels are in order! So seems like it is the discrepancy that is the problem rather than the actual value. this is pretty interesting.